# How to not read the commented lines in from a dataset in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am reading a dataset where there are commented lines. I want to read the data from the dataset except the commented lines.

[image: Dataset]

I tried using this but it only removes the comments on top not all the commented lines in between the dataset.

```
Code

txt = readLines("offline.txt")
txt = txt[4:length(txt)
```

[Dataset link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F3csm5sHJAp0SsV2BPLPFiWerQzELLoi/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try the code below, using `grep` + `readLines`

```
txt<-grep("^#",
           readLines("offline.txt"),
           invert = TRUE,
           value = TRUE)
```

where the idea behind is that you read all lines first and then filter out the commented lines (starting with `#`)